# Spring Boot Maven project will not download the latest Oracle ojdbc8 .jar file when I add the newest <dependency>

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, maven

I am unable to update my Oracle ojdbc driver to the newest version for my oracle database.

I am updating my pom.xml file to the newest version for my 19c oracle database and after its saved it does not add the newest .jar file to my maven dependencies. It creates the folder in the c:-temp-com-oracle folder structure but no .jar file

I am somewhat new to this and not sure what I am missing. My understanding is that spring boot should automatically download the correct dependencies according to the pom file.

Thank you for any assistance.

**INFO**

Java Version 1.8
Oracle 19c DB

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Previous Version (that worked with no issues)**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a wrong group id, correct dependency on maven central: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.oracle.ojdbc/ojdbc8/19.3.0.0/jar

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that since september 2019, ojdbc drivers are now published on maven central repo by Oracle:

https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides

https://medium.com/oracledevs/oracle-jdbc-drivers-on-maven-central-64fcf724d8b

Answer (score 0):

It actually had to do with my Proxy Settings while working remotely. After my settings.xml was updated correctly I had no issues. I did update the groupId as well, thanks